# Can we have one DB for both Preview Site and XPM?

Tags: experience-manager, broker, odata, database, httpupload

We have 2 CDA websites (publication targets), Preview and Live. While setting up the environment, the databases were created for both of these sites through Create Content Delivery DB scripts.

Do we need to create a separate DB for XPM, or it should be configured to use Preview Broker DB?

Also, please let me know whether XPM Service (odata.svc) and broker .NET Service (httpUpload.aspx) should be under a same website in IIS (in an ideal scenario), or we should have them as separate websites?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need two DB

- Broker DB - It is configured in httpUpload and your Delivery
  website
- Session Preview DB - it will be used by Session preview service and this service is consumed by XPM. No separate db for XPM. This db will also configured in storage config of your website.

HttpUpload and Odata.svc would be separate websites

Comment: if it answers you question, you can mark it as answer.

Comment: We have Odata.svc and HttpUpload under a same website on one of our environments and its working absolutely fine.. Can you please let me know the recommended settings??

Comment: Can anyone please have a look at the configuration - i have edited the question for the same. Here, I am using Experience manager and Preview HTTP Upload under same website (HTTPUpload.aspx and odata.svc under same IIS website).. and its working fine. Please confirm if the settings are correct. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please raise new question, else it will be confusing.

Comment: I have raised the question here "http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/7463/storage-settings-under-cd-storage-conf-file-for-xpm"

Answer (score 6):

Session Preview is a feature of Experience Manager that allows editors to make, and then view, updates to content across multiple pages without having to continually check-in and republish the content.

It also ensures that if Editor B updates (a different piece of content on) the same page that Editor A is working on, then this is also reflected in what Editor A sees (within Experience Manager).

Although **it is preferable to have Session Preview available to your content editors**, if you do not require this functionality, then you can choose to turn it off.

Session Preview is disabled within the Experience Manager settings:

[image]

If you choose to disable Session Preview permanently, then you **do not** need a second Content Delivery database.

However, **if you do want to get Experience Manager running fully with Session Preview enabled, then you will need two Content Delivery databases.**

**Further clarification:** If you are using Experience Manager (with Session Preview enabled), then you only need a second Content Delivery database in your Staging (what you have called 'Preview' in the question) environment.