# Storage settings under cd_storage.conf file for XPM

Tags: experience-manager, broker, odata, 2013-sp1, httpupload

We have 2 CDA websites (publication targets), Preview and Live.

As per the question [here](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/7252/can-we-have-one-db-for-both-preview-site-and-xpm), we should have single DB for XPM and Preview Broker. I have HTTPUpload WebService (deployed in IIS as a website) - for preview, where I have deployed odata.svc as well - to reduce the number of IIS web services.

Below is the storages configuration in cd_storage.conf file on my preview cum experience manager website/web-service:

```
<Storages>
<Wrappers>
    <Wrapper Name="SessionWrapper">
    <Storage Id="sessionDB" Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory" Type="persistence" dialect="MSSQL">
    <Pool Type="jdbc" Size="5" MonitorInterval="60" IdleTimeout="120" CheckoutTimeout="120" />
    <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
        <Property Name="serverName" Value="MYDBSERVERNAME" />
        <Property Name="portNumber" Value="1433" />
        <Property Name="databaseName" Value="Tridion_ExperienceManager_Dev" />
        <Property Name="user" Value="adminUser" />
        <Property Name="password" Value="adminPass" />
    </DataSource>
    </Storage>
    </Wrapper>
    </Wrappers>
    <Storage Type="persistence" Id="defaultdb" dialect="MSSQL" Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory">
    <Pool Type="jdbc" Size="5" MonitorInterval="60" IdleTimeout="120" CheckoutTimeout="120"/>
    <DataSource Class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
        <Property Name="serverName" Value="MYDBSERVERNAME"/>
        <Property Name="portNumber" Value="1433"/>
        <Property Name="databaseName" Value="Tridion_ExperienceManager_Dev"/>
        <Property Name="user" Value="adminUser"/>
        <Property Name="password" Value="adminPass"/>
    </DataSource>
    </Storage>  
</Storages>
```

Please let me know if this is correct.

However, XPM and publishing to preview is working fine.

Also let me know where do we use "sessionDB" - coz at present, its not being used anywhere.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what is the question here. Is it "where is the Session DB used?"

Comment: I took it the other way, that Staging website needs only 1 DB- that will be used as Preview broker and XPM. However, it is now clear that odata needs to have a separate DB. In the configuration file, this sessionDB entry is not being used anywhere. Any idea if I am missing any configuration?

Comment: OData should use the Session DB both as Wrapper and Storage. Website (staging) should use SessionDB as Wrapper only.

Comment: is it resolved now?

Comment: @Nuno, what do you mean OData should youse session DB for storage? I thought OData should use the same DB for storage as the website/deployer...

Comment: Actually... Odata in session preview will only use the DB defined in the wrapper. It needs a valid storage or hibernate won't load properly, but you can point the "real" storage to either session broker or "real" broker and it won't make a difference.

Comment: @Saurabh is your problem resolved or still confusion?

Comment: I have a quick question on this, after inline editing in XPM it gets published to Preview target (as configured). Why XPM needs to have a separate DB (of Content Data Store type) - is it for local changes to be saved before committing to the CM DB?

Answer (score 2):

Your "preview" (staging) site indeed requires two databases - one broker, one sessionDB. Your live site requires only one (just the broker). You should configure the sessionDB in the datasource inside of the sessionwrapper, the broker DB in its normal place below.

Comment: I have asked the question - how many number of DBs are required for XPM and preview, http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/7252/can-we-have-one-db-for-both-preview-site-and-xpm, where it was answered that we should use XPM and Preview DB as same. Please have a look.

Comment: Saurabh, when I read the answers to your question there, they do tell you you need two databases to support an XPM site: one broker and one preview.

Comment: That's the same I read - and indeed you need 2 different databases.

Answer (score 0):

as i answered in your previous questions On Staging you need two Separate Databases.

- 1) Exclusively for odataService, (Session-db)
- 2) For Staging website.

So create a separate db. and update above give configuration. 
Is your preview working fine?

just want to give more clarifications.

There would be two different IIS application

- 1 for oData for
- 2 for your staging website. (there would be some setting in website's config as well)

you can refer [documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/UIU4SDLT2011SP1/task_A6B6B3407566454DB05803347B7E987F) (require login)